# RS485 communication with Python

Tags: python, serial-port, communication, rs485

Here's my problem:
I need to send Hexadecimal commands to a device via RS485 to make it work.
I can communicate perfectly with this device using RealTerm, I send my requests and I receive consistent responses.

However now I would like to send them with a python script and I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I don't get any response from the device when I try to send commands to it with my script.

Here is the script :

```
import serial           # import the module
ComPort = serial.Serial('COM3') # open COM3
ComPort.baudrate = 9600 # set Baud rate to 9600
ComPort.bytesize = 8    # Number of data bits = 8
ComPort.parity   = 'N'  # No parity
ComPort.stopbits = 1    # Number of Stop bits = 1

data = bytearray(b'\xfa\x02\x02\x2a\xfe\x0c')

No = ComPort.write(data)

print(data)                      # print the data
dataIn = ComPort.readline()        # Wait and read data
print(dataIn)                      # print the received data

ComPort.close()         # Close the Com port
```

Comment: Excuse me, I should have said this before. The destination is a pressure regulator that can be controlled via rs485

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: In fact I just want to be able to write my command on the COM and receive the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I founded the solution to my problem,
it was just my reading that wasn't getting through, I used .read(6) and it works now.